# retrieving last key in javascript localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am doing a uni assignment so please excuse the coplete lack of knowledge here. I have been tasked with creating a web based app for a "client" that requires me to open an invoice after they have completed all the details, so far I have the form working fine, i can save to localstorage without an issue and can even retrieve the information in the format that I want.

The issue is that if i have multiple "orders' than i can only retrieve the first string saved to localstorage and i cannot figure out how to make it display the newest/last one.

The key is an almost randomly generated number derived from the date as we had to assume a large quantity of orders. I have attached the code below so if anyone can help i would appreciate it. Also I cannot use Jquery or JSON or anything like that. We have been told we are not able to use these. Also i cannot use a server (php etc).

Thanks
Steve

```
<script>
var i = 0;

var itemKey = localStorage.key(i);
var values = localStorage.getItem(itemKey);
values = values.split(";");
var name = values[0];
var company = values[1];
var contactnumber = values[2];
var email = values[3];
var address1 = values[4];
var address2 = values[5];
var suburb = values[6]
var postcode = values[7];
var comments = values[8];
var bags = values[9];
var distance = values[10];
var hdelivery_fee = values[11];
var hprice = values[12];
var htotal_notax = values[13];
var hgst = values[14];
var htotal_tax = values[15];
var hordernumber  = values[16];


document.write('Name: ' + name + '<br />');
document.write('Company: ' + company + '<br />');
document.write('Contact: ' + contactnumber + '<br />');
document.write('Email; ' + email + '<br />');
document.write('Address; ' + address1 + '<br />');
document.write('Address; ' + address2 + '<br />');
document.write('Suburb; ' + suburb + '<br />');
document.write('Postcode; ' + postcode + '<br />');
document.write('Comments; ' + comments + '<br />');
document.write('Number of Bags; ' + bags + '<br />');
document.write('Distance; ' + distance + '<br />');
document.write('Delivery Fee; $' + hdelivery_fee + '<br />');
document.write('Price of Bags; $' + hprice + '<br />');
document.write('Total Ex-GST; $' + htotal_notax + '<br />');
document.write('GST; $' + hgst + '<br />');
document.write('Total Inc GST; $' + htotal_tax + '<br />');
document.write('hordernumber; ' + hordernumber + '<br />');


</script>
```

Comment: You should use JSON for this.

Comment: hey mate, yeah i know and i wish we could, this whole thing would be infinitely easier if i could, but the lecturer specifically said we cant so that sucks for us :-)

Comment: I don't think you got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the last value of an array you should use values[values.length-1].

This will guarantee you get the absolute last one.

Comment: Hey Pbrain, thanks for replying so quickly mate, where would i put that in regards to my code above?

Comment: hey mate, your answer put me on the right track, thank! i ended up fixing it with this
    `var i = localStorage.length-1;`
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

simple put

```
var itemKey = localStorage.key(i);
var values = localStorage.getItem(itemKey); in a loop and increement i each time.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var localStorageKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);

getOrder(localStoragesKeys[localStoragesKeys.length-1]);

function getOrder(itemKey) {
    var values = localStorage.getItem(itemKey);
    values = values.split(";");
    var name = values[0];
    var company = values[1];
    var contactnumber = values[2];
    var email = values[3];
    var address1 = values[4];
    var address2 = values[5];
    var suburb = values[6]
    var postcode = values[7];
    var comments = values[8];
    var bags = values[9];
    var distance = values[10];
    var hdelivery_fee = values[11];
    var hprice = values[12];
    var htotal_notax = values[13];
    var hgst = values[14];
    var htotal_tax = values[15];
    var hordernumber  = values[16];


    document.write('Name: ' + name + '<br />');
    document.write('Company: ' + company + '<br />');
    document.write('Contact: ' + contactnumber + '<br />');
    document.write('Email; ' + email + '<br />');
    document.write('Address; ' + address1 + '<br />');
    document.write('Address; ' + address2 + '<br />');
    document.write('Suburb; ' + suburb + '<br />');
    document.write('Postcode; ' + postcode + '<br />');
    document.write('Comments; ' + comments + '<br />');
    document.write('Number of Bags; ' + bags + '<br />');
    document.write('Distance; ' + distance + '<br />');
    document.write('Delivery Fee; $' + hdelivery_fee + '<br />');
    document.write('Price of Bags; $' + hprice + '<br />');
    document.write('Total Ex-GST; $' + htotal_notax + '<br />');
    document.write('GST; $' + hgst + '<br />');
    document.write('Total Inc GST; $' + htotal_tax + '<br />');
    document.write('hordernumber; ' + hordernumber + '<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `localStorage` and cannot use any client side database then I would save each entry with a key like `new Date().getTime()` with a known string in front of it, so that you have `key-1368910344400`.

When you need to retrieve the last entry then you could do:

```
var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
keys = keys.map(function(key) {
  // check if the current key matches match "key-"
  // if that's the case create a new Date object with the ms obtained by a split
  // return the Date
});

// sort keys and take the most recent
```

This is usually a bad choice but as I understand it you're limited with choices, so you have to stretch things a bit.

If you could use a browser that supports html5 and `webdb` then just throw `localStorage` away and go for that :D, here is an example: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/